# Canon MX420 series MP Drivers

Tags: virus, uninstall

A couple months ago I realized there's an alien software installed in my computer, Canon MX420, I know because I am using EPSON and not Canon, so I decided to uninstall it but it failed, reason, used by another user or program, but there's only one user registered in the computer.

No publisher mentioned in the software identity, Canon MX420 located in System32, ummm? Do you know how to uninstall this software? It's kinda weird tho for me, I am not sure if this a virus or not.

I've also tried to uninstall it via Safe Mode, but it also failed, Print Spooler service not running so the software refused to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the printer driver manually:

1. Login via Safe Mode
2. Find your driver name by downloading the [driver for the MX420](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx420.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=WINDOWS%2010%20(64-bit)).
3. Remove all printers using the MX420 driver.
4. Open Regedit. Remove the folder that matches the printer driver name under the following folder.

   - (on 32 bit(x86) computers)

     ```
     “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows NT x86\Drivers\Version-3”
     ```
   - (on 64 bit(x64) computers)

     ```
     “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3”
     ```
5. Remove the MX420 driver from the following folder:

   - (on 32 bit(x86) computers)

     ```
     “C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\W32X86”
     ```
   - (on 64 bit(x64) computers)

     ```
     “C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64”
     ```
6. Restart the computer
7. Verify that the driver is uninstalled

**References**

- [Manually remove all printer drivers — www.TechIdiots.net - www.ElectronicInsanity.com](https://www.techidiots.net/notes/windows-7/manually-remove-all-printer-drivers)
- [How to manually uninstall a printer driver in Windows | AutoCAD | Autodesk Knowledge Network](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-manually-uninstall-a-printer-driver-in-Windows.html)
- [6 Ways to View and Extract Content from an MSI File • Raymond.CC](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-view-and-extract-contents-from-a-msi-file/)
- [Components of a Driver Package - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/components-of-a-driver-package)